# android upload multipart with progress

Tags: android, rest

i have an rest ws and use PostMapping ...

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public Boolean uploadFile(@ModelAttribute UploadModel model, HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {...}
```

and my uploadModel is :

```
public class UploadModel extends RestRequest implements Serializable {
    private MultipartFile[] files;

    public MultipartFile[] getFiles() {
        return files;
    }

    public void setFiles(MultipartFile[] files) {
        this.files = files;
    }}
```

i need to upload my images (multi file in one request) from android device with show progress ...
can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example how to do it [(Link)](https://medium.com/@PaulinaSadowska/display-progress-of-multipart-request-with-retrofit-and-rxjava-23a4a779e6ba). Also, in the end you can find a link to

Comment: Thank you ... but it's not that i mean .... i ned send files with other parameters ... if you see , my upload model extend other class with params...